# Traduções novas no transifex

Tags: novo-recurso, tradução

O software da Stack Exchange apresentou algumas melhorias e ganharam novas funcionalidades que afetam o SOpt e que ainda não foram ainda traduzidas. Dentre as que mais aparecem estão:

- Código de conduta
- *New contributor* - Traduzi como *Novo usuário*
- *Watched tags* - Traduzi como *Tags acompanhadas*

Por exemplo:

[image: Partes em inglês]

O link do código de conduta é https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Pois bem, eu recentemente traduzi e revi a tradução de várias centenas de strings no transifex, incluindo isso mas também um montão de outras coisas. A minha dúvida é entender qual é o processo que é executado para que elas sejam implantadas em produção e quanto tempo isso demora.

Comment: O CC já está traduzido, só falta revisar e mandar pra lá. Obrigado pelas contribuições.